# Using Proximity receiving a call

Tags: android

Using proximity sensor how can I receive an incoming call?? how will be the service for that??

and this is perhaps i tried to do in my service....

```
try{
    //new DoBackgroundTask().execute()

    Object powerManager = null;
    Method method = powerManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSupportedWakeLockFlags");
    int supportedFlags = (Integer) method.invoke(powerManager);
    Field f= PowerManager.class.getDeclaredField("PROXIMITY_CALL_RECIEVE_WAKE_LOCK");


}
catch(Exception E){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java), the method `answerPhoneAidl` is what you need. Call it when the proximity sensor alerts you.